# Fiware Orion CB subscriptions throttling

Tags: fiware-orion

I have created this subscription :

```
curl localhost:1026/v2/subscriptions -s -S -H 'Accept: application/json' | python -mjson.tool
[
{
    "description": "Update room temperature",
    "expires": "2020-04-05T14:00:00.00Z",
    "id": "5b104ace028f2284c5517f51",
    "notification": {
        "attrs": [
            "temperature"
        ],
        "attrsFormat": "normalized",
        "http": {
            "url": "http://MyUrl/getSub"
        },
        "lastNotification": "2018-05-31T19:19:42.00Z",
        "metadata": [
            "5b019ae132232812eccb6d50",
            "device",
            "16",
            "Auto",
            "30",
            "greater"
        ],
        "timesSent": 1
    },
    "status": "active",
    "subject": {
        "condition": {
            "attrs": [
                "temperature"
            ]
        },
        "entities": [
            {
                "id": "5aff0eef23102126a4aeeea2",
                "type": "room"
            }
        ]
    },
    "throttling": 60
}
```

and even though I have set the throttling at 60 (1 minute if I understand it right), when I change the value of the temperature, orion sends me a notification even if the change happened before the one minute mark (for example I change the temperature value every 10 seconds). Shouldn't a notification be sent only if a change occurred after 60 seconds or am I understanding something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you describe seems to be the right behaviour. I mean, if the subscription has a throttling of 60 seconds, you shouldn't receive any new notifiction until 60 seconds have passed from the previous one.

Possible causes:

- You have another subscripion in place that is being triggered. But I understand this is not the case, as such subscription should be shown in the `GET /v2/subscriptions` result.
- There is a bug in Orion which causes throttling to be ignored. In that case, it would be interesting to do the same test using a subscription created using NGSIv1 (using `POST /v1/subscribeContext`) in order to know the reach of the bug.

Comment: Ok, I tried it again today and it works fine.. I don't know where the problem was! ( I also tried v1 subscriptions, works as intended)